# Can I watch a DotA 2 replay "as a broadcaster"?

Tags: dota-2

I'd like to be able to watch a replay as a broadcaster, allowing me draw on the screen (not just the minimap) as casters do.  Is there a way to do this, or can you only do this in a live game where you're sitting in a "broadcaster" slot?

Comment: Just curious, but why? I don't think you can watch replays with another person (afaik) so it doesn't seem like there would really be a point.

Comment: @turbo He might want to make videos, or show replays to his dog/cousin/friend/whatever

Comment: There's plenty of good reasons for wanting to do this. For example if he's new to broadcasting, maybe he wants to get practice in on non-live games before doing something with a live audience. He also might want to put videos up on YouTube or elsewhere in a similar fashion to the live streams.

Comment: Ah both valid points that I hadn't considered.

Comment: @Thebluefish hit the nail on the head.  My friend and I are getting into casting and want to try it out - ideally we'd love to both be physically IN the same game replay, but I don't think that possible (so we've settled for downloading and starting at the same time).

Comment: also @T_O my dog is a captive audience for all of my DotA rantings :)

Comment: Another potential idea is for both of you to just spectate random high-level live games(so you can both be in the game and in-sync) then record the audio. It might also be more enjoyable since you won't be able to anticipate the result of the game based on time left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given [this](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=137741) recent suggestion to the Dota 2 dev forums and [an older](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=53874) post, I do not think that drawing on the terrain while spectating or watching a replay is possible at all in the current build of Dota 2.

You could probably pick up some support if you were to post this on a site with a larger Dota 2 following, like Reddit's [/r/dota2](http://www.reddit.com/r/dota2), and possibly get Valve to notice. Response times on dev.dota2 about small issues like this are famously slow.

Aside from that, not having this feature while trying to become an amateur caster should not be a big deal. If you cannot cast without it, your casting abilities lack more than you may think. Always try to work on saying relevant information to the game, but not having dead air; try not to be like Ayesee back when he was new to Dota, *"turning a bagel into a breadstick"* comes to mind, just don't do it.

Since you mentioned that you are working with a friend, try to figure out each of your strengths. If you have paid some attention to casters like Tobi, they typically pair up with a color commentator who can offer more indepth knowledge about the game, like Synderen for example. If you think you know more about the game than your friend, try to let them handle generating excitement and you explain the pro's actions.